# I've downloaded Apache POI, but when I try to use it my code doesn't compile

Tags: java, apache-poi

I've recently download `poi-src-3.2-FINAL` from [poi.apache.org](http://poi.apache.org/download.html). Now I can't write these:

```
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.*;
```

Now I can't use the classes of `HWPFDocument` and `WordExtractor`.  I can only

```
import org.apache.*;
```

Did I forget to download any other thing?

Answer (score 6):

"src" usually indicates a package containing *only* the source code, not the compiled classes. Check to see if there is a "bin" download available for you.

Update: the binary release is indeed named poi-**bin**-3.2-FINAL, [here is a download link](http://www.signal42.com/mirrors/apache/poi/release/bin/poi-bin-3.2-FINAL-20081019.zip).